# How can I share executables from my Linux build computer with my macOS editing computer?

Tags: linux, ssh, git, remote-access, data-transfer

I currently have a setup where I edit code on my Mac, push the changes to a GitHub repository, pull the changes on my Linux build server (controlled via SSH), then build the program. The issue is that I have to test my program in a graphical environment, which I don't think I have access to through SSH. Because of this, I have to get the build product onto my Mac somehow so I can run it in a graphical environment. How do I do that?

Comment: is the build server yours and under your exclusive control? how do you normally access it? generally speaking, a build server has to have some means to publish builds, so its common to use some kind of file sharing service, be it Web, FTP, SMB, NFS, SSHFS/SFTP, or whatever else. Note however that you should expect to be able to build at least the component you are working on (and a sufficient test-harness) on your dev system. If not your dev system is insufficient for the task you are putting it to.

Comment: @Frank_Thomas The program will only build on Linux (or at least, Linux is the easiest platform to build it on), and the build server is my home PC. I need to test the program locally on my Mac because I cannot get X11 working over SSH.

A file sharing solution is something I should try to set up.

Answer (score 0):

To actually copy the files, it should be sufficient to use SFTP, since the remote machine is accessible by SSH.  There's an `sftp` command, and you can also use `scp` to copy files over one by one from the command line.

If your goal is to run Linux executables natively on macOS, that's simply not possible.  Linux and macOS use different executable formats (ELF and Mach-O), different C libraries, and different ABIs.  In addition, if you had trouble getting X11 working over SSH, you're also going to typically have trouble getting it to work natively on macOS, which doesn't use or ship with X11, and has to have it installed as an add-on.

You may find that a Linux VM is a good choice here.  There are many possible tools for this, but if you have Homebrew installed, you can install QEMU and use it for this purpose.  Once you have an appropriate distro installed, you can use `scp` or `sftp` to copy the files to the VM and run it in a graphical environment.  You could also use `sshfs` to mount a portion of the build server over SFTP as well.

Comment: I actually do have X11 working on macOS (I even compiled a Linux X11 app from source code on my Mac once, but that's besides the point). Also, the executable is not for Linux or macOS, it is for the Nintendo 64. I didn't feel the need to mention this fact, however. My final solution was to set up an SMB server on the Linux PC and connect to it to access the files; I also set up a symlink to make it easier to access the remote file on my Mac.